# Kill or Destroy or Exit Thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I create Thread in java, I want to kill or destroy or exit it and restart the same thread again. There are properties to kill or destroy thread but are deprecated now. Here is may same thread code

```
`Thread ball6Animation;
public void ball6Animation()
{
ball6Animation=new Thread(){
public void run()
{
while(true){
try{
sleep(1000);
// Some Logic
}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}}};
ball6Animation.start();
}
```

`
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Instead of using the `Thread` class directly, consider creating a new class which implements the `Runnable` interface.

Comment: You need a flag which will allow you to exit the loop

Answer (score 3):

please take a look at the [Java Thread Primitive Deprecation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

They explain really good why you shouldn't do that and how you can achieve your goal safely.